# Messy code presented when knitting to word from R Markdown

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, windows-7-x64

When I code the matrices and functions into R Markdown, it presents successfully, like the following image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVQvo.png)

The matrices and functions can be knitted to html. However, when I knit to word document, it appears messy codes, like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn5Le.png)

In addition, I also cannot knit to pdf document since it occurs the following errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...

l.93 \left[\begin{array}\
pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS 000.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output 000.pdf --template "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-32~1.3\library\RMARKD~1\rmd\latex\DEFAUL~3.TEX" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43
Execution halted
```

I am using Windows 7 (64-bit) and RStudio 3.2.3.

Does anyone help me deal with these problems?

Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using Microsoft Office Word 2007.

Comment: Does it help if you ensure the `$$` characters are on their own line? (Move the `y =` down so it's no longer on the same line as the opening `$$`)

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't work. When I move the "y =" down, it still appears like "$$y=\left[\begin{array}\ 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{array}\right]$$" in Word document.